# Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel'. Available commands: web

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, dnx, kestrel-http-server

Trying to run simple webapi application on docker (deployed to Ubuntu Linux) i face strange exception when attempting to run container:
Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel'. Available commands: web.

What ive done so far.. I have uploaded my aspnet5 solution to Linux machine and run to publish it: dnu publish --framework dnxcore50 --configuration Release --wwwroot "wwwroot" --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --iis-command "web"

Next ive done docker build to create an image and then try to run it with: sudo docker run -t -d -p 8000:8000 myimagename

Looking at the docker logs i see an exception shown above.

Ive logged into the container to see folders structure and all look good. Verifyid dnx in container and the one i used to build solution are the same.

Using latest available microsoft/aspnet image - rc1-update1

Any ideas??

Comment: Ok, i have got some luck to finally run my app with the following:
1. I have removed ENTRYPOINT from my Dockerfile to be able to run container.
2. I have connected to the container with "sudo docker exec -t -i mycontainer /bin/bash"
3. Then i did "dnu restore" inside the image
4. I was able to run a command with "dnx web"

So, it looks like the problem is with the binaries versions difference. How is this possible? How can i avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by runnning this commands in the Dockerfile before the ENTRYPOINT:

```
ADD ./app
#SOLUTION
WORKDIR path_to_your_sources
RUN dnu restore
#########
WORKDIR /app/approot
ENTRYPOINT "./web"
```

Although the error message suggests that it is expecting the command "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel" in

```
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  }
```

It would be very strange, but to check if that was the case anyway, I tried:

```
    "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  }
```

And it didn't work.
`dnu restore` fixed it, don't know the relation to the error message yet.